# Test if an interface equals a type parameter

Tags: delphi, generics, interface

I have a list that can hold interfaces.
I want to have a remove function that only deletes items that support a particular interface.

```
type
  TMyList<T: IFoo> = class
    procedure Remove(const Item: T); overload; 
    procedure Remove<I: IBar>(const Item: T); overload;
  end;

procedure TMyList<T>.Remove<I>(const Item: T);
begin
  if Supports(Item, I) then Remove(Item);
end;
```

> E2250 There is no overloaded version of 'Supports' that can be called with these arguments

Is there a way in which this can be done?

Comment: Did you generate a GUID to the interface? Compiler identifies interfaces by its GUID.

Comment: You stated that you want to remove items that implement particular interface.
If that's so , then list should contain objects, not interfaces. Supports method is intended to be used like:
Supports(myObject, IMyInterface, Intf), where Intf is variable of type IMyInterface, 
and if myObject implements it then that it is assigned to Intf. (That's example for particular overloaded version of Supports, the one that I think you should use)

Comment: @David Heffernan, Yes, you can constrain a generic param to be an interface.  The problem is, it only applies to the generic *expansion*.  The type info doesn't make it to the compilation stage.  That is, even though "I" was constrained to be IBar, the compiler doesn't know that it's supposed to be an interface when it's referenced by the call to "Supports"

Comment: @DaveOlson Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, the two interfaces should have a GUID declared with them (If you haven't done this already).

```
type
   IBar = interface
   ['{08C764E8-3EF4-42A7-94B7-8D1C5371DF25}']
   end;

   IFoo = interface
   ['{30B9440D-A012-4C7D-8422-A80D7E18F4E5}']
   end;
```

Then, you should be able to change the call to "supports" to this:

```
uses System.TypInfo;

function TMyList<T>.Remove<I>(const Item: T);

begin
   //if Supports(Item, I) then Remove(Item);
   if Supports(Item, GetTypeData( TypeInfo(I) )^.GUID) then Remove(Item);

  //  ...
end;
```

While the compiler does not "know" that "I" is an interface type, you do - because you constrained it.  So, it's safe to extract the GUID out of the TypeData for "I".

---

Generic type constraints (either class, or interface or record) *do not* declare or refine the data type of the generic parameter in the code where that are referenced or consumed.  Rather, they simply allow the compiler to restrict how the generic type may be used.

```
type
   IBar = interface
   ['{08C764E8-3EF4-42A7-94B7-8D1C5371DF25}']
   end;

   IFoo = interface
   ['{30B9440D-A012-4C7D-8422-A80D7E18F4E5}']
   end;

   IFoo1 = interface(IFoo)
   ['{6C3D06C9-C0B7-45CD-80F2-45123ECC5E9C}']
   end;
   IFoo2 = interface(IFoo)
   ['{9C3AB5F7-E88C-4620-AFC5-B83340048531}']
   end;


   TMyList<T: IFoo> = class
   end;
```

The < T:IFoo > constraint will allow these:

```
 var
     L : TMyList<IFoo>;
     L : TMyList<IFoo1>;
     L : TMyList<IFoo2>;
```

But not this:

```
     L : TMyList<IBar>;
```

And, most importantly, in the 3 valid expansions, "T" **does not** become an interface type.  It is still generic or "type-unknown" in the compiler's eyes.

The "constructor" constraint is the one exception to this rule. It will require the generic parameter to be a **class type** but more importantly, it allows instantiation of the target class through a parameter-less constructor *without* type casting.

```
type
   TMyClass = class
      constructor Create;
      procedure   DoSomething;
   end;

constructor TMyClass.Create;
begin
end;

procedure TMyClass.DoSomething;
begin
end;

type
   TMyGeneric2<T:constructor> = class
      procedure Perform;
   end;

procedure TMyGeneric2<T>.Perform;

var
   x : T;

begin
   x := T.Create;   // This is allowed...
   x.DoSomething;   // ...but this is not.
end;
```

When you use generic type parameter constraints, **you are not resolving the type** of the generic parameter.  You are merely setting-up some **rules** for the compiler to follow when that generic type is consumed.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, although you cannot pass an interface type parameter as such, you can pass a `TGUID` and assign an interface type to a `TGUID`, provided that you declared a GUID in the interface declaration to begin with.

Example

```
type
  IFoo = interface
    ['{93863A49-5014-4AE5-A7CF-F3F2E044CE57}']  //<Ctrl>+<Shift>+G
   ....
  end;

  IBar = interface(IFoo)
    ['{88888888-5014-4AE5-A7CF-F3F2E044CE57}']
    ....
  end;

  procedure TFooList.Remove(const Item: IFoo; const MustBeA: TGuid); {overload;}
  begin
    if Supports(Item, MustBeA) then Remove(Item);

  ....
  for i:= 0 to count-1 do begin
    //Only remove IBar16 items
    MyFooList.Remove(FooList[i], IBar16);
  end;
```

Comment: There is no need to pass-in the GUID;  it can be safely extracted from the type-info since the generic parameter was constrained to be an interface of (at least) type IFoo.  It can be done with one change to the call to "Supports".  See my answer.